# sumo with openstreetmap, error during netcovert for osm to xml

Tags: openstreetmap, sumo

I am looking for an error when trying to convert `.osm` `openstreetmap` file to `.xml`. I have downloaded `openstreempmap` file `map.osm` and when I try to convert using command `netconvert --osm-files map.osm -o map.net.xml`

> error: White space expected in file 'built in type map' at line/column
>   2/50. The types could not be loaded from 'built in type map'. Quitting
>   (on error)

I am using **Ubuntu18.04, Sumo-1.1.0**

Had anyone came across this issue? I can not find any support regarding this specific problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK3Vp.jpg

Comment: How did you install sumo? Which Xerces version do you use?

Comment: I installed sumo by downloading tar file, I did install xerces-c3.2 but not sure how to check version.

Comment: Could you retry with the ppa (see https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Downloads#Repositories) or is it important that you build it yourself?

Comment: Did you build with cmake? Can you post the build log somewhere?